# Wordpress wpdb->insert returns int(0) => doesn't insert anything, no errors!

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am really clueless. I want to do an insertion in my WordPress plugin the problem is it doesn't return any errors nor it insert the stuff!

I  don't know how to fix this and really need your help. In the following code i used example names, but i used the character `-` for these in case of that my real table has also names with `-` in it as well as the table itself.

Usually there is no problem, just use some back ticks `` and the stuff works well, but now welcome to WordPress. Is there a problem with the insertion function in WordPress or is there any other possible error?

I really tried to fix this by myself but i failed.

```
$insertion = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'table-name-of-plugin', array(
                'column-name' => $stringValueForC1,
                'second-column-name' => $stringValueForC2
            ), array('%s, %s'));
```

If i use `var_dump()` for the insertion variable i get: `int(0)`.
string `0` for `wpdb->last_error` and `bool(false)` for `wpdb->last_query`.

I also double checked my table name and it is 100% correct!
What can be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is wrong.

On your code is should be

```
$insertion = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'table-name-of-plugin', array(
'column-name' => $stringValueForC1,
'second-column-name' => $stringValueForC2
    ), array('%s', '%s') );
```

Notice the change from

```
array('%s, %s')
```

to

```
array('%s', '%s')
```

Also, since you are setting the format for both of the value as string. I recommend that you just use

```
'%s'
```

The format parameter accepts either array or string. If it's string, the string will be used as the format for all the values. Source - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row

Comment: big thanks to you! You really helped me out i swear u i checked all possible things, but this little mistake i didn't recognize so thank you! Also i will follow your suggestion in just using a string instead of an array ;-)

Comment: Glad i'm of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue exist in the data type format. You've passed `array('%s, %s')` take a closer look, instead of two values you've passed them as a single value, which leads to incorrect data type format.

It should be `array('%s', '%s')`

So the final correct statement will look like this

```
$insertion = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'table-name-of-plugin', array(
    'column-name' => $stringValueForC1,
    'second-column-name' => $stringValueForC2
        ), array('%s', '%s')
);
```

Comment: also thank you for your answer, donMhi.co was a little bit faster :-)

Comment: oh yes sorry my mistake, but he also mentioned that i should use only a string if the data types are equal.

Comment: No worries at all buddy :) Good luck!